# In MongoDB, how to filter by location, sort by another field and paginate the results correctly?

Tags: mongodb

When i don't use pagination, everything works fine (i have only 3 records in this collection, so all of them are listed here):

```
db.suppliers.find({location: {$near: [-23.5968323, -46.6782386]}},{name:1,badge:1}).sort({badge:-1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f33ff549112b9b84f000070"), "badge" : 3, "name" : "Dedetizadora Alvorada" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f33ff019112b9b84f00005b"), "badge" : 2, "name" : "Sampex Desentupidora e Dedetizadora" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f33feae9112b9b84f000046"), "badge" : 1, "name" : "Higitec Desentupimento e Dedetização" }
```

But when i try to paginate from the first to the second page, one record doesn't show up and one is repeated:

```
db.suppliers.find({location: {$near: [-23.5968323, -46.6782386]}},{name:1,badge:1}).sort({badge:-1}).skip(0).limit(2)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f33ff549112b9b84f000070"), "badge" : 3, "name" : "Dedetizadora Alvorada" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f33feae9112b9b84f000046"), "badge" : 1, "name" : "Higitec Desentupimento e Dedetização" }

db.suppliers.find({location: {$near: [-23.5968323, -46.6782386]}},{name:1,badge:1}).sort({badge:-1}).skip(2).limit(2)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f33feae9112b9b84f000046"), "badge" : 1, "name" : "Higitec Desentupimento e Dedetização" }
```

Am i doing something wrong or is this some kind of bug?

---

**edit:**

[Here is](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-856?focusedCommentId=99221&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-99221) a workaround for this. Basically you shouldn't mix $near queries with sorting; use $within instead.

Comment: @doorat, can you please add the location co-ordinates of all three documents.. i ll run it over here and let you know

Comment: Actually your query has no much sense. `$near` without `$maxDistance`-parameter returns all list of items, sorted by distance from given point. You tries to sort by another field. So why do you need `$near`, then?

Comment: @Dao, you're right, but i'm actually using the $maxDistance attribute in the code, i just forgot to include it in these sample queries.

Comment: @RameshVel, they were [-23.5952334, -46.6824619], [-23.7169609, -46.70785129999999] and [-23.5392895, -46.6819143], respectively, if you still want to play with this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open issue regarding the same problem. Please have a look & vote [Geospatial result paging fails when sorting with additional keys](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-856)